# Tabbed browser equivalent in IE

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, bho

I'm trying to port this little piece of code from a FF extension to IE (7, 8 and 9).

```
var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var gBrowser = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").gBrowser;
var tab = gBrowser.addTab(url);
var thetab = { "tab": tab };
var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(tab);
```

The goal is to create a Firebug-like panel at the bottom of the screen (the tab loads html code which does all the fancy formatting stuff).

Unfortunately, I don't know how to create tabs in IE. Any ideas?

I'm using a BHO that listens for OnDocumentComplete and calls JS code in a Windows Scripting Component.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in IE.  If you want to create a panel at the bottom of the screen, you need to build a [horizontal explorer bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753590%28VS.85%29.aspx).